# How to install psycopg2 on windows 7

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I have tried `pip install psycopg2` and following errors i got:

Error:

```
(ScrapeProj) C:\Users\e2sn7cy\Documents\GitHub\scraper>pip install psycopg2==2.5.4
Collecting psycopg2==2.5.4
  Using cached psycopg2-2.5.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\e2sn7cy\appdata\local\temp\pi
p-build-joij3x\psycopg2
```

Then I tried using `easy_install` by downloading the `.exe` file from [Stickpole](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) and I got following errors :

```
(ScrapeProj) C:\Users\e2sn7cy\Envs\ScrapeProj\Scripts>easy_install psycopg2-2.6.1.win-amd64-py2.7-pg9
.4.4-release.exe
Processing psycopg2-2.6.1.win-amd64-py2.7-pg9.4.4-release.exe
psycopg2.tests.test_module: module references __file__
psycopg2.tests.test_types_basic: module references __file__
creating 'c:\users\e2sn7cy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-sa7asq\psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg' and
 adding 'c:\users\e2sn7cy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-sa7asq\psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp'
to it
creating c:\users\e2sn7cy\envs\scrapeproj\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg
Extracting psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg to c:\users\e2sn7cy\envs\scrapeproj\lib\site-packages
Adding psycopg2 2.6.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\users\e2sn7cy\envs\scrapeproj\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for psycopg2==2.6.1
Finished processing dependencies for psycopg2==2.6.1
```

But when I again tried to install through pip I am getting a new message that its already there :

```
(ScrapeProj) C:\Users\e2sn7cy\Envs\ScrapeProj>pip install psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2 in c:\users\e2sn7cy\envs\scrapepro
j\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg
```

Then I thought ok I should try to import and then I got this error:

```
(ScrapeProj) C:\Users\e2sn7cy\Envs\ScrapeProj>python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\e2sn7cy\Envs\ScrapeProj\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg\psycopg2\__
init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Now I am not able to understand what to do. Thanks

Edit 1:
I have also added my PostgreSQL path to system path variables

`path:C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4`

`path:C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer was given by Craig Ringer, I am just adding this because I came to know that we should first check which version of 64 bit or 32bit Python installed on our system. If you have 32 bit version of Python and if you will try to install 64bit, then you will get the above error on importing.
For checking the version:

`import platform`

`platform.architecture()`

and you will get an output like this:

`('32bit','WindowsPE')`

Comment: Good point, and thanks for following up. You should free to accept your own answer here.

Comment: Thanks Craig, this would be my first answer on Stack.

Answer (score 5):

Download the [pre-packaged binary release of psycopg2 for Windows](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) rather than compiling it yourself. It's a pain to compile on Windows. This is [explained in the install documentation for psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html).

You might need to remove your half-installed attempts.

Comment: you want me to download the source package from here

Comment: @RahulShrivastava Er. No. **Use the binary installer for Windows**. See the heading **Windows packages** in the linked page.

Comment: I have also tried downloading the exe file from Jason Erickson's website, I tried that as you can see. I have got it install using easy_install.

Comment: @RahulShrivastava I see. I didn't notice that, because I've never tried installing it via `easy_install` before, rather I've just executed it.

Comment: I did not find the file

Comment: @Alex78191 The answer is very old. A Google search for "download psycopg2 binary windows" now finds https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose the appropriate version from this page:

   > http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/
2. Right click and select `copy link address`
3. Back at home, use `easy_install <<Paste URL Here>>`
4. Freeze your new requirements: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: Note, this is only necessary for older versions of psycopg2. As of 2.7, it installs successfully via pip.

Comment: This saves my life. Successfully install psycopg2 2.6.2. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Now that psycopg is in PyPI (as of March 2017 it appears), just fire up a command prompt with administrator privileges and install like so:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install psycopg2
```

If you don't have pip installed, follow the instructions here to do that first:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/2540707

Answer (score 2):

pip install psycopg2-binary

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Compilers Installation and configuration

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Before do anything, install or upgrade the Setuptools Python package. It contain compatibility improvements and add automatic use of compilers:

pip install --upgrade setuptools

Step 2: Download and install PostgreSQL

Before you continue to install python packages inside you virtualenvs download postgres itself. It contains files that are needed when compiling the psycopg2 python package. Just use the PostgreSQL installer(version 10 for example).

Important: add the postgres C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin folder to your path. It contains the .dll needed for psycopg2.

Step 3: Install psycopg2

pip install psycopg2

Tested on Windows 7 + python 3.7

Answer (score -1):

The best/easiest way of installing packages (including this problematic psycopg2 ) for python on windows platform is to:

1) install anaconda and ... 
2) use Anaconda Navigator GUI to install/update packages.

By this one avoids many inconsistencies and conflicts that occurs among different packages versions and installations.

Comment: What is difficult to install msvc build tools?